# show <hr> tag with font-awesome icon and text together inline with responsive behaviour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show three different elements inside `<div>` tag in one single line with complete responsive behavior. Three elements are, (i): font-awesome icon user, (ii): label text and (iii): hr tag.  I am using bootstrap.

Here is my HTML,

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form">
            <div class="row traveller-divider">
                <div class="inline-block">
                    <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                    <label>Traveller</label>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried something with CSS but it doesn't work. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: What is 'complete responsive behavior'?

Comment: @LuudJacobs : The complete line with three elements should remain one line in tab as well as in mobile. That means the hr tag must change its width according to device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS Positioning. Make `.traveller-divider` - relative & make `hr` - absolute.

Have a look at the snippet below for better understanding:

```css
.traveller-divider {
  position: relative;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form">
            <div class="row traveller-divider">
                <div class="inline-block">
                    <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                    <label>Traveller</label>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: First thank you for your answer. I have wrote the same CSS and changes also my HTML structure as you mentioned. But the horizontal line is not appearing. Is it because of the nested HTML structure? Please check the updated HTML structure in question.

Comment: @harsh You are missing `.traveller-divider { position: relative; }`. I've updated my answer with your updated HTML, please have a look and let me know if this helps?

Comment: I did the same, but it still doesn't show me the horizontal line. When I inspect the element <hr> then It is behind the two elements. And when I remove the property position: absolute then it appears under the two elements...:(

Comment: @harsh I've updated `z-index: 1` of <hr> and updated `z-index: 2` & `position: relative` of `.inline-block`. Have a look at the updated answer. This should now work. `z-index` of `.inline-block` should always be more than that of `<hr>`, keep in mind. Hope that works. Let me know.

Comment: Perfect solution. It works perfectly and also smooth and responsive. thank you for your support.

Comment: @harsh Its my pleasure. If this worked for you, you can accept and upvote this answer.

Comment: Yes I already accepted the answer but upvote I cannot, because of the low reputation yet..;)

Comment: @harsh Not an issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row divider">
     <label>User <span class="fa fa-user"></span></label>
     <hr>
</div>
```

Not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: No, with this code the hr tag automatically shown into new line. I don't want that. I want all three elements into one line. And the font-awesome icon must appear before the user label.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the hr to be at the side of the icon and label, you need to position it relatively and give the icon and label a background color (the same color as the containing div). Otherwise, you'd have to use float to position the hr and give it a defined width, which would not be responsive.

Given your HTML, this is what I'd do:

```
.fa, label { 
   display: block; 
   background: #fff; 
   float: left; 
} 

hr {position: relative; top: -0.5em; z-index: -1; clear: both; }
```

You'd have to tweak the hr's `top` position to match what you want.

Here's a working pen: http://codepen.io/vic3685/pen/GNqeQQ

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. In codepen it is working correctly how I want. but I have applied the same CSS rules into my HTML then the hr tag is not showing the horizontal line. Is it because of the nested HTML structure I have? Please check my updated HTML structure.

Comment: With your updated structure, it still works in codepen. What's your CSS? Adding position:relative to .traveller-divider is one option, but without seeing the rest of your CSS, it's just a guess.

Comment: Here is my CSS:  .traveller-divider {
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 10px;

      .fa, label {
        display: block;
        background: #fff;
        float: left;
        padding: 0 5px 0 0;
      }

      hr {
        position: relative;
        top: -0.5em;
        z-index: -1;
        clear: both;
      }
    }     I think the problem is nested CSS. I apply .fa, label and hr rules inside the traveller-divider class. I also applied outside but it still doesn't work..:(

Comment: Yeah, there's obviously more to it. Adding the Bootstrap css and the code you just provided, it still works in Codepen: http://codepen.io/vic3685/pen/GNqeQQ. Is there any chance you can provide a link to the entire thing?

Comment: And to be clear, do you actually see the <hr> before you implement my code? Because it is a very light grey, so I switched it to red. If your background is a little darker than white, it could be invisible.

Comment: Hey, yes your solution works on codepen but not in my problem. Checkout the accepted answer. It works fine for me. BTW many thanks for your support.